# Union type of "keyof" and "string" with working autocompletion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types

I want to expose a method that takes some Union type as parameter and provides autocompletion for that. As this union type could be extended via declaration merging, autocompletion is a key feature here.

But in cases where the user doesn't use TypeScript when using my library, or does not want to add particular typings to the declaration, it should alternatively accept a `string` alternatively to the union type.

**In short:** I want autocompletion for the union type, but also allow any string that does not match it.

Example with only the union type:

```js
export interface Values {
   'variant-a': undefined,
   'variant-b': undefined,
   'variant-c': undefined,
}

function doAThing<T extends keyof Values>(name: T): void {
  console.log(name);
}
```

Things I tried:

1. Adding a function overload:  `function doAThing<T extends keyof Values>(name: string): void;` - does merge types with `keyof Values`, and becomes string for both then. No autocompletion.
2. Make the generic type a union with `string`: `<T extends keyof Values | string>`- merges to only `string`. No autocompletion as well.

Comment: What's the meaning of adding type `string` for people who don't use Typescript? When they use the function there isn't any type checking anyway.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear about that: it matters to typescript users, as those should be able to choose if they want to merge their own definitions into the interface, or not.

Comment: Do you want Typescript to suggest 'variant-a', 'variant-b' and 'variant-c', but not mark an error if the developer writes something else?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729#issuecomment-460346421):

```
export type Values = {
   'variant-a': undefined,
   'variant-b': undefined,
   'variant-c': undefined,
}

type AnyString<T> = T | (string & {});

function doAThing<T extends keyof Values>(name: AnyString<T>): void {
  console.log(name);
}

doAThing('variant-b');  // Autocompleted
doAThing('variant-d');  // Not autocompleted, but still accepted
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Can you maybe explain why adding `& {}` does the trick?

Comment: I think that `string & {}` is not reduced to `string` and therefore cannot merge with `keyof Values`.